# DataGridView Event - which one to choose

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, events, datagridview

I'm looking for an event that occurs right right after loading and after sorting.

I have a piece of code that colors some of the Rows in a DataGridView control. But when I sort the style changes are lost. I need the right event to tap into to redo the coloration step after the load/sort events. Trying to right clean code ... so I was looking for a single event that I could use to cover both situations.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView.Sorted executes right after a sort.

Maybe sort the data in the control after loading initially?  That way you would call Sorted on the load.